# How to add arrays for key and object in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, nsdictionary

I have 2 arrays. **Array A** arrayA[0] contains {a,b,c,d,e...} and **Array B** arrayB[0] contains {a,b,c...}. And both arrays are mutable and have many objects. In `NSMutableDictionary` for each element in Array A (taken as key) should store entire Array B.

**For example:**

(key value)Array A[0] have entire (object value)Array B(0...200)

(key value)Array A[1] have entire (object value)Array B(0...200)

(key value)Array A[2] have entire (object value)Array B(0...200)

**My code:**

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
{

    [someDictionary setObject:arrayB forKey:arrayA[i]];

}
```

***this doesn't work and i tried this too :***

```
[someDictionary initWithObjects:arrayB forKeys:arrayA[i]]
```

Comment: Please provide more information; "It doesn't work" is not enough.

Comment: more info on the bug is required. I mean show us the logs.

Comment: error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Channels copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbd2ae20'

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NSString` for storing key in key-value pair. So i would recommend

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {

    NSString *str=(NSString *)arrayA[i];

    [someDictionary setObject:arrayB forKey:str];

}
```

Comment: You might have something, however casting it to `NSString *` won't make it a string.

Comment: Yes, that's correct but the point is that we need string for "key". I hope you got my point.

Comment: reason: '-[Channels copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbd09d20'

Comment: use NSMutableDictionary instead of NSDictionary

Comment: i am using mutable dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine in principle. Obviously being fixed to 100 elements is not nice, so I'd write

```
for (id key in self.arrayA)
    [someDictionary setObject:self.arrayB forKey:key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer. I don't know brother whether I am understanding your question correctly or wrongly.

Try my code:

```
NSMutableArray *tempA=[NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *tempB=[NSMutableArray array];

for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
{
     [tempA addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",a]];
}

NSMutableArray *dataArray=[NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableDictionary *dict;

for (int i = 0; i < [tempA count]; i++)
{
        for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
        {
            dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            NSString*  localTemp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key-%@",[tempA objectAtIndex:i]];
            [tempB addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",a]];
            id object=[tempB objectAtIndex:a];
            [dict setObject:object forKey:localTemp];
            [dataArray addObject:dict];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Dictionary is---->%@",dataArray);
```

Comment: tbh i did not understand what you meant by this code. Actually with simple arrays it works fine, but my arrayA[0] has {a,b,c,d,e} and arrayA[2] has {a,b,c,d,e}

Comment: the same thing here a[0],a[1],and so on... will have a entire value of b array.

Comment: actually my error is with copyWithZone, so i am trying to fix it

Answer (score -2):

```
 NSArray *arrayA = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
    NSArray *arrayB = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3",@"4", nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for(int i =0 ; i<[arrayA count];i++)
    {
        [temp setObject:arrayB forKey:[arrayA objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
```

Comment: error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 196465664 beyond bounds [0 .. 298]'

Comment: this one works. i tried it. Wat type of error do u get?

Comment: @user2885077 yeah this code works but my array has objects like arrayA[0] contains {a,b,c,d,e} also arrayB[0] contains {a,b,c}